# What makes networking packets?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

I'm confused about what parts of a linux system do what when it comes to networking.  I'm looking for a good reference about more than just the network layers.  Starting with network layers though, using the OSI 7 Layer model:

- 7-Application
- 6-Presentation
- 5-Session
- 4-Transport
- 3-Network
- 2-Data Link
- 1-Physical

At what point do networking go from hardware to kernel to application software?  I suspect at **(1)** it's all hardware and just signals on wires or over wifi  At **(2)** it reaches some network interface, but do they ***make*** frames, or do the interface drivers?  **(3)** network, IP, I'm guessing handled by the OS? **(4)** still kernel or at least sockets provided by low-level libraries in C/C++?  **(5)** Not entirely sure, but thinking this is still low level, where `SYN`, `SYN/ACK`, `ACK` take place.  And then finally **(6)** user-space, or application space of actual data, but in raw form.  And then **(7)** all application, and the application can determine the intents and behavior of network communication.

Comment: **Too many questions** in the single question post. "I'm looking for a good reference about more than just the network layers." - Stack Overflow is bad place for request "references" and other **off-site** resources.

Comment: No, this isn't on the wrong SE site, rather it is a type of question which does not fit the purpose of SE sites.